# In Excel aggregate values from a column if the following values are larger than zero

Tags: excel, loops, excel-2010, do-while

I would like excel to iterate through a column of precipitation values and keep adding them as long the value is larger than zero. The table for example looks like this with the required result in NewCol.

```
Date   prec    NewCol
x      10      10
x      8       18
x      3       21
x      0       0
x      1       1
x      0       0
```

I would like to use the value 21 (and all other values with largest values) to assess consequtive rainfall days. Wondering if this is possible in Excel? Haven't been able to find the solution in Mathlab.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: No need for vba a formula would do it `=IF(OR(ROW() = 2,B2 = 0),B2,B2+C1)`  Put that in C2 and copy down.

Comment: Why would you use the ore statement with the ROW? Especially because it is empty between the brackets?

Comment: It is testing whether the formula is in row 2 or not.  `ROW()` will return the row number in which the formula is.  When the row is the first of the dataset in this case row 2 we want the value in column B not the addition of the title row and Column B.

Comment: After the holliday break it took me a while to figure out, but it worked perfectly. Thanks!